# AWS presigned url query string explained

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, put, pre-signed-url

I am trying to understand how `PUT` method works for uploading a file to s3 using presigned url.

I am generating a presigned url using `boto3` library for a put call. The generated url looks like this:

```
https://My_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=<ACCESS_KEY>&Signature=<Signature>&x-amz-security-token=<SEC_TOKEN>&Expires=<Expires>
```

In order to generate a `v4` signature, I need `KeyId` and `SecretAccessKey`.

If we look at the url above, we can see that the `KeyId` matches to `AWSAccessKeyId` but there is no `SecretAccessKey`.

I have generated the presigned url using an account that has administrative privileges (it also has read/write access to the `s3` bucket). From my understanding, any non privileged user can use the information in the link to upload a file to `s3`.

There is quite a bit of documentation but frankly, I am extremely confused.

I would appreciate if someone can explain 
1. how the signature is used.
2. Where is the `secret_access_key`? Is this derived from signature?
3. How do I correctly generate a `v4` signature using the uri query parameters from the signed url?

When I tried to use the signature I generated, I get an error

> The authorization header is malformed; the authorization component
>    "Credential=SIGNATURE/20191217/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request" is malformed.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: You mean the code where the presigned url is generated? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

Comment: Client code is in dart. A complete thread on this discussion cane be found [here](https://github.com/arnemolland/sigv4/issues/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was, the location of the bucket is in different region than the code that generates the pre-signed url.

The following code works for me.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))  

response = None
try: 
  response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    'put_object', 
    Params={
      'Bucket': 'bucket-name-to-presign-south1', 
      'Key': 'car.jpg'}, 
      ExpiresIn=5000) 
  print(response)    
except Exception as e: 
  print("In client error exception code") 
  print(e)
```

The following reference helped me to look in the right direction:
https://javiermunhoz.com/blog/2016/02/01/on-s3-endpoints-regions-signatures-and-boto-3.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204437/discussion-on-answer-by-arun-k-aws-presigned-url-query-string-explained).